# Download file from url to cordova app error

Tags: android, cordova, download

I'm making an app that needs to download images from my site and store them in the phone, but when I try phonegap shows me all the errors that could happen. What can I do to correct this =/ ?

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    "/",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
```

The errors shown are :

```
Download error source " the url used"
download error target: " the target used  "
upload error code 1
```

I'm using cordova 2.2.0

Here is the logcat error log:

```
 12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186): {"target":"\/","source":"http:\/\/developer.android.com\/assets\/images\/home\/ics-android.png","code":1}
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186): java.io.FileNotFoundException
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.getFileFromPath(FileTransfer.java:794)
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.access$700(FileTransfer.java:62)
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:631)
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-06 09:07:26.413: E/FileTransfer(2186):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are so close, it's just your target file that is wrong. Try:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    "file://sdcard/ics-android.png",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
```

You need the "file://" prefix and you can't save to "/" as you don't have permissions.

Comment: @Simon MacDonald I was trying the same way but i am getting error saying ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined. what could be the issue Please help.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I'm testing on `genymotion android emulator` and my path is `file://storage/emulated/0/Download/nn.txt`. It can be a permission issue ? Also, how to ask for permissions to save in `/` location ?

Comment: *update* I tried with different variations and even the same code as posted here, nothing worked for me so far.

Comment: I was able to get it working (in cordova 3.4), using the below answer, thanks!

Comment: For others who stumble upon, adding `file://` won't work in 3.4

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it and this work in Android but I have not check yet in ios.And the download is successfull as I am using it in my project.

```
enter code here
 function fun(){
var dfd = $.Deferred(function (dfd){
var remoteFile = "Your link";
var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false},
    function(fileEntry) {
var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
            localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }// You need to write IOS instead of Android

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
    dfd.resolve('file downloaded');
     // Do what you want with successful file downloaded and then
    // call the method again to get the next file
    //downloadFile();
            }, fail);
             }, fail);
            }, fail);

           });
            return dfd.promise();

        }
                fun().then(function(msg){
            if(msg==="file downloaded")
            {
            alert("Download complete");
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Download error")
            }
            });
            function fail(){
            alert("error");
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it says `device is not defined`. Removed `device` check and now it shows the error popup.

Comment: According to this [`bug`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6094) in cordova 3.4 we have to use `.toURL()` instead of `.fullPath()`.

Comment: If device is not defined then You have to add the permissions in app/res/xml/plugins.xml   and add this line   <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
and in app/AndroidManifest.xml add this line   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
then it will not show any error like device is not defined.